# Regression - out-of-sample forecasting

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, forecasting, predict

I try to figure out how to deal with my forecasting problem and I am not sure if my understanding is right in this field, so it would be really nice if someone can help me. First of all, my goal is to forecast a time series with regression. Instead of using ARIMA model or other heuristic models I want to focus on machine learning techniques like regressions such as random forest regression, k-nearest-neighbour regression etc.. Here is an overview of the dataset:

```
    Timestamp          UsageCPU     UsageMemory   Indicator  Delay
2014-01-03 21:50:00    3123            1231          1        123
2014-01-03 22:00:00    5123            2355          1        322
2014-01-03 22:10:00    3121            1233          2        321
2014-01-03 22:20:00    2111            1234          2        211
2014-01-03 22:30:00    1000            2222          2         0 
2014-01-03 22:40:00    4754            1599          1         0
```

The timestamp is increased in steps of 10 minutes and I want to predict the independent variable UsageCPU with the dependent variables UsageMemory, Indicator etc.. At this point i will explain my general knowledge of the prediction part. So for the prediction it is necessary to separate the dataset into training, validation and test sets. For this my dataset that contains 2 whole weeks is separated in 60% training, 20% validation and 20% test. This means for training set I have the first 8 days included and for the validation and the test set I have each 3 days. After that I can train a model in SparkR (the settings are not important).

```
model <- spark.randomForest(train, UsageMemory ~ UsageMemory, Indicator, Delay, 
                        type = "regression", maxDepth = 30, maxBins = 50, numTrees=50, 
                        impurity="variance", featureSubsetStrategy="all")
```

So after this I can validate the results with the validation set and compute the RMSE to see the accuracy of the model and which point have to tuned in my model building part. If that is finished I can predict on the test dataset:

```
predictions <- predict(model, test)
```

So the prediction works fine, but this is only an in-sample forecast and can not be used to predict for example the next day. In my understanding the in-sample can only used to predict the data in the data set and not to predict future values that can happen tomorrow. So really want to predict for example the next day or only the next 10 minutes / 1 hour, which is only possible to success with the out-of-sample forecasting. I also tried something like this (rolling regression) on the predicted values from random forest, but in my case the rolling regression is only used for evaluating the performance of different regressors with respect to different parameters combinations. So this is in my understanding no out-sample forecasting.

```
t <- bind(prediction, RollingRegression3 = rollApply(prediction, fun=function(x) mean(UsageCPU), window=6, align='right'))
```

So in my understanding I need something (maybe lag values?), before the model building process starts. I also read a lot of different papers and books, but there is no clear way how to do it and what are the key points. There is only standing something like t+1, t+n, but right now I do not even know how to do it. Would be really nice if someone can help me, because I tried to figure this out since three month now, thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify my understanding: you built a random forest model, but you don't know how to use it to predict future CPU usage, right? This may not be related to "out of sample" data, correct me if I'm wrong. Because, "out of sample" data is the data not used for model training, as oppose to future (unknown) data?

Comment: Yes right, I want to use my model to forecast the next 12/24h for example (in-sample). As I mentioned, the dataset is separated into training, validation and test set, but for me it is only possible to predict on this test and validation set. My goal is to put data from the last week into the prediction and on the basis of this it can predict me the next 12/24h. Oh okay sorry, I think there was a misunderstanding with the term "out-of-sample" for me.

Comment: Ok, there are some ideas which may not be a solution: for predicting the next 12/24h, the random forest model needs to know the value of UsageMemory, Indicator, and Delay in the next 12/24h which we don't have.  Hence you can try either building other models to forecast those variables then predict CPU usage. Personally, I'd like using time series to solve this type of problem. ML is not a swiss knife to solve all problem.

Comment: Just to point out complications you haven't asked: have you checked autocorrelation levels in your data? If the levels are significant, you'll likely need to work in some domain other than time. A straightforward-ish way if your data are evenly sampled in time is to use the FFT of the data for training. Use the inverse FFT for interpreting predictions.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s see if I get your problem right. I suppose that, given a time window, e.g. 144 last observations (one day) of UsageCPU, UsageMemory, Indicator and Delay, you want to forecast the ‘n’ next observations of UsageCPU. One way you could do such a thing, using random forests, is assigning one model for each next observation you want to forecast. So, if you want to forecast the 10 next UsageCPU observations, you should train 10 random forest models.

Using the example I began with, you could split the data you have in chunks of 154 observations. In each, you will use the first 144 observations to forecast the last 10 values of UsageCPU. There are lots of ways in which you could use feature engineering to extract information from these first 144 observations to train your model with, e.g. mean for each variable, last observation of each variable, global mean for each variable. So, for each chunk you will get a vector containing a bunch of predictors and 10 target values.

Bind the vectors you got for each chunk and you’ll have a matrix where the first columns are the predictors and the last 10 columns are the targets. Train each random forest with the n predictors columns and 1 of the targets column. Now you can apply the models on the features you extract from any data chunk containing the 144 observations. The model trained for target column 1 will ‘forecast’ one observation ahead, the model trained for target column 2 will ‘forecast’ two observations ahead,  the model trained for target column 3 will ‘forecast’ three observations ahead...

Comment: Well, I am not sure how this should work, because right now my training set consists of 1008 observations (1 week). In my understanding the more data are used to train, the more accurate will get the model. Splitting the data as you said to chunks of 154 observation would be the same output but only for one day. Doing this 10 times with 10 random forest regressions I will have a similar outcome and also a bad accuracy because of the small amount of training data. Maybe I understand your solution wrong, but in my opinion it is the same approach with different sizes of the training length.